# Method to render Quill output in browser?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, quill

I'm trying to verify how the output from a Quill Rich Text Editor will be rendered in the browser as a HTML element embedded with a string variable. I just want to see how whitespace and format will render. When I tried `useRef`, the app crashes without any error message. I'm just left with a blank screen. I'm not sure how to approach debugging in this situation and why React.js behaves this way.

I also tried with `useState` by having the hook `onChange` inside of the `<div>` where Quill is initiated. This method did not work either. The state is not updating.

I appreciate any ideas. Thank you for your time!

```js
export default function Edi() {
  const text = useRef([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    new Quill("#editor", {theme: "snow"});
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <div id="editor" ref={text}></div>
      <p>{text}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

```js
export default function Edi(){
  const [text, setText] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    new Quill("#editor", {theme: "snow"});
  }, [])
  
  return (  
    <div>
      <div
        id="editor"
        data={text}
        onChange={(event, editor) => {
          const data = editor.getData()
          setText(data)
        }}
      ></div>
      <p>{text}</p>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Why not to use a wrapper like https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-quill ?

Comment: First obvious debugging step: in snippet 2, add a `console.log` statement inside the onChange to show the value of `data`. Make sure to stringify the value when logging. Also, it seems obvious that you can't just `<p>{richTextData}</p>` as though it's a simple string -- it will either be HTML or some kind of AST that requires conversion to HTML, both of require more preparation to display than just this.